# How can I enable bluetooth at boot in Lubuntu 18.10?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, mouse, bluetooth, startup

I'd like to use my bluetooth mouse before login.  Currently it only works after login.
What I've tried:

added rfkill unblock all to rc.local

Udev rules

Neither worked.  Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around added the line

bluetoothctl connect "mouses unique id" to rc.local (run at startup)

and now the mouse connects at boot.  Not sure why it wasn't attempting to connect automatically as all settings in bluetoothd main.conf say that it should and its a trusted device.  Maybe a lubuntu or apple issue (magic mouse)